# std::map emplace fails with explicit constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class A {
public:
    explicit A(int x) {}
};

vector<A> v;
v.push_back(1);  // compiler error since no implicit constructor
v.emplace_back(1); // calls explicit constructor
```

The above is from a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_utkragEjRA) by David Stone. What I fail to understand is why does `emplace_back` call
the explicit constructor? I do not see anything in the C++ standard that
makes this legit. Only after listening to David Stone's youtube video,
I found out about this.

Now, I try the same with `std::map`.

```
map<int, A> m;
m.insert(pair<int, A>(1, 2)); // compiler error since no implicit constructor
m.emplace(1, 2); // compiler error since no implicit constructor
```

Why does `emplace` fail here ? If `emplace_back` can call explicit
constructor, why doesn't `emplace` do the same ?

Answer (score 4):

`emplace` method inserts elements by explicitly calling constructor with `placement new operator`. While emplacing into map you need separately forward arguments for constructing key and value.

```c++
m.emplace
(
    ::std::piecewise_construct // special to enable forwarding
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple(1) // arguments for key constructor
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple(2) // arguments for value constructor
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `emplace` functions invoke your constructor as described in the standard at http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#15.5

> `T` is `EmplaceConstructible` into `X` from `args`, for zero or more arguments `args`, means that the following expression is well-formed:
>
> `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, args)`

This means that it ultimately comes down to your allocator. Looking at the reference for what that calls means, we can check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct

We see that if the allocator does not have a construct member function, or if it is `std::allocator`, then the call is equivalent to

`::new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

For `std::map<int, A>`, the type `T` in your expression is `std::pair<int const, A>` and `args...` is `1, 2`. So to know whether your call to `emplace` is well-formed, we just need to decide whether a call to `std::pair<int const, A>(1, 2)` is valid. So for that, we look at the documentation for `std::pair`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair

The constructor in question is listed as `/*EXPLICIT*/ constexpr pair( const T1& x, const T2& y );` (assuming C++17). In other words, it is just like calling a regular function that accepts `int const &` as the first argument and and `A const &` as the second. `A` is only explicitly constructible from `int`, so your call is ill-formed. The `emplace` call is only saving you from `explicit` on any objects you are directly constructing, which in this case is just `std::pair`, not any arguments to that type.

Answer (score 1):

`m.insert(std::pair<int, A>(1, 2))` compiles, I don't know why it doesn't compile for you. Maybe forgot `-std=c++11` flag? That's because the `std::pair` constructor explicitly calls the constructor when it copies the elements into `first` and `second`.

If you want to emplace into a `std::map`, you have to specify a key and a value in a `std::pair`. You can use `std::make_pair` for that:

```
m.emplace(std::make_pair(1, 2));
```

This compiles, as the pair will get constructed in place in the key/value pair, and the explicit constructor will be called.

Comment: This has to do with the conditionally explicit constructors, formally added in C++17, but implemented by recent versions of GCC in C++11 onwards.

Comment: I used c++14 flags, but I have gcc version 4.9.2. I tried with gcc 6.2 and now   both "m.insert(pair<int, A>(1, 2)) and m.emplace(1, 2);" compile. Also, for map.emplace, I do not believe there is a need to use make_pair.