# Map emplace with value having private constructor results in C2664 (VC 12.0; C++11)

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair, emplace

The following code compiles without error in Visual Studio 2015 (VC 14.0; C++14):

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class Caller;
class SomeClass
{
private:
    friend class Caller;

    SomeClass(std::string& arg1, std::string& arg2)
    :
    m_arg1(arg1),
    m_arg2(arg2)
    { }

    std::string m_arg1;
    std::string m_arg2;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> SomeClassPtr;

class Caller
{
public:
    void PopulateMap()
    {
        std::string key("test");
        m_map.emplace(key, new SomeClass { std::string("1"), std::string("2") });
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, SomeClassPtr> m_map;
};

int main()
{
    Caller caller;
    caller.PopulateMap();
    return 0;
}
```

However, downgrading to Visual Studio 2013 (VC 12.0; C++11) results in C2664:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(600): error C2664: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'SomeClass *' to 'const SomeClassPtr &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=SomeClassPtr
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'SomeClass *' to 'const SomeClassPtr'
1>          Constructor for class 'std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>' is declared 'explicit'
...
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434691/stdmap-emplace-fails-with-explicit-constructor) suggests that the problem is that the value argument to std::pair is not explicitly constructable.

The workaround is to forward the arguments as follows:

```
m_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(key),
    std::forward_as_tuple(new SomeClass(std::string("1"), std::string("2"))));
```

I now understand why the VC 12.0 example fails, but what part of the standard is being exploited in the original (VC 14.0) example for it to compile?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions) says Visual Studio 2015 has "improved support" for C++ 14/17:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/